# JavaScript Cookies check/set/delete

Tags: javascript, cookies

I just wanna check if a cookie exists,
set/reset the cookie for 1 day,
and delete the cookie when the window/tab is closed

I'm trying to do this in JavaScript, but hell JS is one dumbass language(I swear), add to that I'm stupid.

Anyways here's what i'm doing:

```
function checkcookie(name)
{
    //Can't figure this one out
    //I want to check wheather the cookie is set or not
    //if yes
    //{ reset cookie + ... }
    //else
    //{ set cookie + ... }
}

function setcookie(name,value,day)
{
    var expireDate = new Date();
    expireDate.setSeconds(expireDate.getSeconds()+day*24*60*60*1000);
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + ";path=/;expires=" + expireDate.toGMTString();
}

function delcookie(name)
{
    setcookie(name,"",-1);
}
```

Any kind of answer is appreciated and thx in advance.

Comment: Maybe you can try changing `expireDate.setSeconds((expireDate.getSeconds()+day*24*60*60*1000);` to `expireDate.setSeconds(expireDate.getSeconds()+day*24*60*60*1000);`?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to reinvent something that has been done billions of times before already. Why are you trying to write a library in a language you hate? Just search "javascript cookie library" or plugin and use that :p

Comment: JavaScript is a fantastic language. The way *browsers* make cookie information available to it is asinine. Please, do put the blame where it belongs.

Comment: I'm glad T.J. said what he did because the difficulties in working with cookies have nothing to do with JavaScript. First, The browser offers a miserable "API" for it. Second, cookies exist as a stop-gap for areas in which HTTP was lacking. Third, cookies can be modified from many places, not just scripts. And fourth, expiration on cookies is confusing given the difference between "session" cookies and cookies with a specific expiration date. JavaScript has nothing to do with any of this. I have a a lot of experience in this area...

Comment: "JavaScript is a fantastic language" o_O pfff you kidding right.
Trying to learn the syntax of JS gives me nightmares, it got absolutely 0 syntactic sugar. And like the man said, “If you can't explain it simply, you don't understand it well enough”

Comment: @Shepherd: No, I'm not kidding. It's clear you simply don't understand the language, which is quite different from many of the other current major languages. If you have to work in JavaScript, I recommend strongly that you lose the attitude and take the time to learn the language properly; otherwise, you'll continually bang your head against your misconceptions and get irritated. If you don't have to, by all means don't, and keep building your skills in other languages. I'm not saying it's perfect in any way (it isn't), but then I've never seen a language that was.

Comment: Ok fair enough. thx for your replies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test the Quirksmode code here:
http://jsfiddle.net/67RFW/

The code is working so it must be something else causing your problem... so see what it does for you if you run it in jsfiddle.net - that might help determine if its a browser setting

Comment: (BTW I created a new post so the link didn't get lost way down the comments)

Comment: Well, its not the code or your browser settings... can't think what it could be. Were you running it locally or uploading it to a server?

Answer (score 5):

Quirksmode.org has [an excellent article](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html) on writing wrapper methods for interacting with `document.cookie` (an inherently unfriendly object).

The article explains how to implement the following methods: `readCookie`, `createCookie`, and `eraseCookie`.

From these methods, it's easy to implement your `checkCookie` function, that is, if `readCookie` returns null or not.

Here's your `checkCookie`:

```
function checkCookie(name)
{
    return readCookie(name) != null;
}
```

Here's the other three functions that the article provides:

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, try it.

```
  function checkcookie(name)
    {


  if (name!=null && name!="")
  {
     //reset cookie
     cookie_value="test";
     document.cookie=name + "=" + cookie_value;
  }
else
  {
     //if there is no cookie, create a new one
     cookie_value="test";
     document.cookie=name + "=" + cookie_value;
  }
}


    function setcookie(name,day)
    {
        var expireDate = new Date();
        expireDate.setSeconds((expireDate.getSeconds()+day*24*60*60*1000);
        document.cookie = "Name=" + name + ";path=/;expires=" + expireDate.toGMTString();
    }

    function delcookie(name)
    {
        setcookie(name,"",-1);
    }
```

Comment: o_O your checkcookie does't even have a return in it

Comment: No need to return, just use your own codes to set cookie. Updating cookie is setting cookie. Just use your own expire date and set your cookie.

Comment: hey man checkcookie(name) doesn't check the cookie, it checks name then sets cookie no matter what. The test if (name!=null && name!="") is usless + that's not what i wan't