# remain same clicked checkbox result when page refreshing while highlighting table record

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code is written to accomplish 2 function
           1. highlight table record when checkbox is clicked
           2. Keep results same eventhough the page refreshed
But with this code neither table record get highlighted or nor page keep result same when refreshed.
I posted the same question earlier also, Some people suggest me on **localstorage**. I tried with that also. But my knowledge is so poor that I couldn't understand the explanation given completely. A help would be highly appreciated as I have to submit this as my university assignment

```html
 <style>
    #cb3.highlight .label {background-color:yellow;}
        #cb2.highlight .label {background-color:green;}
        #cb1.highlight .label  {background-color:red;}
    }
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    Array.prototype.remove = function() {
        var what, a = arguments, L = a.length, ax;
        while (L && this.length) {
            what = a[--L];
            while ((ax = this.indexOf(what)) !== -1) {
                this.splice(ax, 1);
            }
        }
        return this;
    };
    
    var checked = [];
    
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if (localStorage.getItem("checked") == null)
            localStorage.setItem("checked", checked);
    
        $("#Table input").click(function() {
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                $(this).parent().parent().addClass("cb3.highlight .label ");
                checked.push($(this).attr("cb3"));
            } else {
                $(this).parent().parent().removeClass("cb3.highlight .label ");
                checked.remove($(this).attr("cb3"));
            }
            localStorage.setItem("checked", JSON.stringify(checked));
        });
    
        var saved = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("checked"));
        for (var i = 0;i < saved.length; i++) {
            var itemAtIndex = $("#" + saved[i] + "");
            itemAtIndex.click();
            itemAtIndex.parent().parent().addClass("cb3.highlight .label ");
        }
    });
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if (localStorage.getItem("checked") == null)
            localStorage.setItem("checked", checked);
    
        $("#Table input").click(function() {
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                $(this).parent().parent().addClass("cb2.highlight .label ");
                checked.push($(this).attr("cb2"));
            } else {
                $(this).parent().parent().removeClass("cb2.highlight .label ");
                checked.remove($(this).attr("cb2"));
            }
            localStorage.setItem("checked", JSON.stringify(checked));
        });
    
        var saved = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("checked"));
        for (var i = 0;i < saved.length; i++) {
            var itemAtIndex = $("#" + saved[i] + "");
            itemAtIndex.click();
            itemAtIndex.parent().parent().addClass("cb2.highlight .label ");
        }
    });
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if (localStorage.getItem("checked") == null)
            localStorage.setItem("checked", checked);
    
        $("#Table input").click(function() {
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                $(this).parent().parent().addClass("cb1.highlight .label ");
                checked.push($(this).attr("cb1"));
            } else {
                $(this).parent().parent().removeClass("cb1.highlight .label ");
                checked.remove($(this).attr("cb1"));
            }
            localStorage.setItem("checked", JSON.stringify(checked));
        });
    
        var saved = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("checked"));
        for (var i = 0;i < saved.length; i++) {
            var itemAtIndex = $("#" + saved[i] + "");
            itemAtIndex.click();
            itemAtIndex.parent().parent().addClass("cb1.highlight .label");
        }
    });
    </script>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
    
    <table id="Table" border="1">
          <tr id="cb1">
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="cb1" value="y" /></td>
            <td class=label>Click me</td>
        </tr><tr id="cb2">
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="cb2" value="y" /></td>
            <td class=label>Click me</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="cb3">
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="cb3" value="y" /></td>
            <td class=label>Click me</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: maximum how many bytes you may need to store your data? If you want to store less than 4MB you can also use the [cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie).

Comment: I just want to store states of 3 checkbox only. How can I use cookies?

Comment: here is the quick [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464502/javascript-cookies-check-set-delete) see the jsfiddle link in the answer.

Comment: Could you please elaborate this thing more?

Comment: I just looked your code. you bind 3 functions to every click. Are you familiar with jQuery?

Comment: No. To be honest I am force to code. Now I should however do this and submit to university. I edited this code with my very little knowledge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things that need to be fixed:
You have repeated same piece of code thrice, if you were doing that because 3 checkboxes, its not required. you have used a selector which will select all three checkboxes and attach the event handler for click.

you are adding classes wrong, just give the names classes to be added to 'addClass()' method

`$(this).attr("cb3")`, is wrong, you want to use `$(this).attr("name")`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
 <style>
    #cb3.highlight.label {background-color:yellow;}
        #cb2.highlight.label {background-color:green;}
        #cb1.highlight.label  {background-color:red;}
    }
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    Array.prototype.remove = function() {
        var what, a = arguments, L = a.length, ax;
        while (L && this.length) {
            what = a[--L];
            while ((ax = this.indexOf(what)) !== -1) {
                this.splice(ax, 1);
            }
        }
        return this;
    };
    
    
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var checked = [];
    
        $("#Table input").click(function() {
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                $(this).parent().parent().addClass("highlight label");
                checked.push($(this).attr("name"));
            } else {
                $(this).parent().parent().removeClass("highlight label ");
                checked.remove($(this).attr("name"));
            }
            localStorage.setItem("checked", JSON.stringify(checked));
        });

      if (localStorage.getItem("checked") !== null){
 var saved = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("checked"));
 for (var i = 0;i < saved.length; i++) {
      $("[name='" + saved[i] + "']").trigger('click');
 }
        }
    
    });
    </script>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
    
    <table id="Table" border="1">
          <tr id="cb1">
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="cb1" value="y" /></td>
            <td class=label>Click me</td>
        </tr><tr id="cb2">
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="cb2" value="y" /></td>
            <td class=label>Click me</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="cb3">
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="cb3" value="y" /></td>
            <td class=label>Click me</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing out my mistake Mr.Dij. Your solution work  perfect. Thank you in advance

Comment: In this code, I try to remove <tr id="cb1"> and include id="cb1" in <td id="cb1>. But in that case Highlight did not work. Please can you explain where should I change?

Comment: Mr.Dij I include image which depicts what my project should be. According to the requirement all 3 checkbox should lie in a same row. Then user click start, pause or stop check box.